# Why does java.awt.Dimension use doubles for height and width?

Tags: java, image

From [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dimension.html):

> The Dimension class encapsulates the width and height of a component
>   (in integer precision)

Why not represent these as an `int` or `long`?

Comment: The answer, sadly, is just bad API design. There's no good reason for it.

Comment: 225 questions without an accepted answer?! :-P

Comment: @PeterLawrey - I have tried several times to go over past questions and accept some more answers. If you find any questions where you think I should accept an answer, please point them out.

Comment: If no one can answer my question, but I believe I now know the answer, I provide an answer which I accept.  This hopefully helps those who would also like to know the answer to that question.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - I do too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reckon it is because the superclass, Dimension2D, declares the method to return a double. For most solutions an integer is fine, but when you wish to create a Dimension2D type for vector graphics, returning dimensions as something else than integers would be necessary.

Comment: Can you expand on why something else than integers would be necessary for vector graphics?

Comment: Vector graphics keeps it shape even when scaled.  You can make it 10x the size or more without "graininess".

Comment: Check out Esko's answer, it explains that dimensions are not bound to pixels so it allows for really good scaling

Answer (score 2):

I believe the original explanation for this is that dimensions are usually relative, for example the far left edge of the image is `0.0` and far right of the image is `1.0` (*and same for vertical dimension, of course*). Pixel (*or point*) is just a sample from a relative point on that range, so if you have an image with width of 350 pixels, the row's 210th pixel is at point `0.6` on the dimension range.

This, of course, is just the reasoning behind the used data type. In practice this doesn't usually apply since instead of being an inclusive range from `0.0` to `1.0`, range from `0.0` to `[width in pixels].0` is used instead.

---

*Addentum:* Range from `0.0` to `1.0` should make perfect sense to you if you're even slightly aware of [vector calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus).

Answer (score 0):

It has to because it's parent class `java.awt.geom.Dimension2D` is based on doubles.